# Cancelling Kronecker Powers of Positive Semidefinite Matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are complex $d\times d$ matrices. Suppose moreover that they are Hermitian positive semidefinite and that for some $k>0$
$$ A^{\otimes k} = B^{\otimes k},$$
where $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker (i.e., tensor) product. Is it then true that $A=B$? Or can we at least relate $A$ and $B$ somehow?

Thank you in advance for your help.